"have three children" versus "to be mothers of three"

... A similar change, but to a lesser extent, can be seen in the figure for those who were mothers of three, which declined from 27.4% in 1981 to 21.5% in 2006.

I'm writing a report on data about women having given birth to different numbers of kids. Is mothers of three natural here, or is it too informal and doesn't fit the context?
===
The table below presents the number of children ever born to women aged 40-44 years in Australia for each year the information was collected since 1981.




None
One child
Two children
Three children
Four or more children




year
%
%
%
%
%


2006
15.9
13.2
38.3
21.5
11.0


1996
21.8
11.3
38.2
24.6
13.1


1986
9.7
8.7
35.6
27.0
28.9


1981
8.5
7.6
29.0
27.4
27.6




There is nothing 'informal' about mother of three.

I don't know if you explicitly want to distinguish women giving birth to three children from women who currently have three children, because children sometimes die. But in practice, "mother of three" is likely to be fine, and if you're just talking about that chart people will understand what is meant.

Why do you feel the need to say "for those who were mothers of three"?   You could say, simply, "for mothers of three".   Is this an exercise on how to use demonstrative pronouns?

The blurb describing the chart is not very clear, however.  Does ever born mean that those births could have occurred when the mother was outside the 40-44 age range? If so, what then is the significance of the 40-44 age range? Why did the data focus only on women who were in that range?  Or are we to ignore the word ever and just assume that chart reflects the data for mothers who gave birth to children while they were in that age-range?

Thank you all for the information. @TimR Yeah now that you've talked about it, I realized "for those" is redundant here. Sometimes when I write, I translate English to my mother tongue and it just sounds okay that I don't notice the redundance.

I think 'ever' implies that we don't have to care about whether the mothers gave birth to any children after each of those years.

@KenAdams Again with the embedded image with text. Please fix this.

@gotube I realized most of the times the images with text I attach to my posts are not indispensable. I often attach them as some extra information just in case. In those cases, can I just post an image because even if you read in on a phone, it still doesn't make the above question harder to understand? I find it a little hard to type all the information in a table out when there's so much data like this.

@KenAdams I understand it's a pain to format tables, but if we allow one image, others will follow suit. So, it's either type out a formatted table, or remove the graph entirely. Just to show you I'm a good sport, I've just re-learned how to format tables, and I've done this one for you. You can use this one as a template to fix the others.

Thank you. I've just used the format to edit another post. But I wonder why the forum created the image function yet doesn't let people use it.

Have a present from me: The table below shows children born to women aged 40-44  in Australia for each year information was collected as of 1981. AND: for those who bore 3 children.

I think "mothers of three" is ambiguous. You should be very specific, because it's not at all clear exactly what that category is. Is it "Women who gave birth to three children?" Or is it "Women aged 40 to 44 who gave birth to their third child?" The table makes no mention of the age 40-44 criteria that you include in your introductory sentence. (Then you have an overriding descriptor that these are women in Australia.)
When you're presenting data, you need to describe the data very accurately so it's clear exactly what you're presenting. Your data table should have a title that specifies exactly what data it contains. Just as the rows have a label ("Year"), so should the columns (it's not clear what that is). The age bracket is never mentioned in the table, but it's clearly important. The fact that this is data from Australia can probably be handled outside the table or in a note below it.
You're wise to show your data presentation to someone who knows nothing about it so you can get good feedback about whether you've successfully eliminated the ambiguity.
Stephen Few has some excellent blog posts about how to present tabular and graphical data (one example).

The problem isn't being informal. "Mother of three" is not specifically informal and fits with a formal style just fine. But using that phrase would be much more problematic than a mere style mismatch.
The problem is that "a woman who has given birth to three children" and "a mother of three" don't mean the same. A woman who has adopted and raised three children is a mother of three without ever giving birth.
When writing a report, you have to be very specific and unambiguous about what you mean. So do not say "mothers of three" in this context, it's factually wrong.
